# Finding the cheapest available accommodation in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, search

I am doing a long-distance walk to the Caspian Sea, and I'm trying to do it cheaply. (I do a mixture of wild camping, cheap hotels, campsites, hostels, apartments, Airbnbs, Couchsurfing, and miscellaneous in order to keep costs down.) Currently the maximum I will pay for a hotel is 500 Turkish Lira, and accommodation at this price point will generally be well above my needs.

I am trying to become more efficient at finding the cheapest hotels. Is there any way I can program the Google Maps app to filter/show results for

hotel OR otel OR hostel OR apart OR pansiyon OR campsite

which has a phone number listed and either

- has offered rooms on booking websites for 750TL or less at some point the past month
- No prices listed, but is within 100 meters of a hotel which has offered rooms on booking websites for 750TL at some point in the past month
- has between 1 and 50 reviews
- is a campsite, hostel, one-star hotel, or serviced accommodation
- has a live chat option
- lists a mobile phone number rather than a landline (=> contactable via WhatsApp, where I can use Google Translate).

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Google Maps is a cross-platform app. Is this question about using the Web, Android or the iPhone and iPad app?

Comment: I am using the android app, but also the website app. I have a feeling I would get the best answers for the website app, so I would like my question to be about that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I asked because while the core features are the same, others are not available in the other apps, even Android iPhone and iPad apps might not have all the features that the others have. Sometimes is temporary, i.e., a new mobile feature might be first released for Android, but others might never be released in both mobile apps. If you have a question specific about the app for Android, please post that question on [android.se]. Another related site is [travel.se].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps might not be the best place to search for the cheapest accommodation when you are open to other accommodations that aren't hotels when planning a journey.

Google Maps focuses on providing a map-based user interface. It's optimized to navigate around geographic locations, and the search features are optimized to find stuff primarily based on things that could be mapped to geographic coordinates, [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) and [longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude), like country, city, address, landmark.

On the other hand, Google Search has been optimized to help users refine their search queries that might end on a commercial transaction, in this case, booking an accommodation reservation, as this kind of use gives them earnings for advertising, their booking hotel partnerships, and the services provided to the business to improve their online presence and optimize their indexation (SEO). About this there is a related product: [Google Travel](https://www.google.com/travel/).

It's worth noticing that Google Search is integrated with Google Maps. It might show a knowledge box with details of the region, landmarks, city and even accommodation providers. The knowledge box of accommodation providers might include the details you seek.

Google Search has a specific filter for maps, and many results will include a link showing their location using Google Maps and user contributions like photos and videos.

Start by reading

- [Search for hotels on Google](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/6276008?hl=en).
  Summary:

  - Go to https://www.google.com/travel/search
  - Or go [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), or one of the domains for the countries you will visit during your travel, and include the word `hotel` in your search query.
- [Book hotels on Google](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/7029040?hl=en).
  You might book accommodation by following links to Google's hotel booking partners. The first step is to search for a hotel (or accommodation) in Google Search.

You might also want to use specialized sites. I suggest you take a look at [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com), another site of the Stack Exchange network that is focused on travel questions.

Google Maps is best for taking advantage of searching for accommodations based on the distance from a particular location, using it together with [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) to create a map of your travel plan. It includes some controls to sort results by price, distance and possibly others and shows reviews and user contributions.

The search experience might vary depending on the region that you will be searching. Google has a program called [Local Guides](https://maps.google.com/localguides/) to promote user contributions to Google Maps. Check out to see if there is a Local Guides group in the region that you will visit. They might guide you on how to get the most from Google Maps in their region.

---

## Search for accommodations in Google Maps

When opening Google Maps (https://maps.google.com). It will show some buttons to help search. The buttons might vary according to the context, like if you haven't done any search yet or are searching for a city, a landmark, etc. Some of the buttons that might be shown over the map panel are:

- Hotels
- Vacation Rentals

  - Houses
  - Apartments
  - Other
- Amenities
- Rating
- Hours
- All Filters

The Google Maps side panel might show controls to help refine your search. These controls depend on the context, like if you clicked the Hotels button or the keywords included in the search query.

### Hotels button

Clicking this button will show a panel with tools to refine the search. One of these tools is a slider bar to set the range of prices.

1. Type a region, landmark, city, etc.
2. Click the Hotel button.
3. Refine your search

### Keywords

Besides using the Hotels button, you might want to try using keywords. Here are a few suggestions:

- camping
- campsite
- hostel
- lodging

The search results will show the accommodation amenities if they were contributed (from a database, partner, by users, by the owner, etc.) to Google Maps. Click on a result to view the detail card. The detail card includes controls to help to compare the results.

## References

- [How Google sources and uses information in local listings](https://support.google.com/local-listings/answer/9851099?hl=en)

## Resources

### From the Keywords (Google public relations / corporate) blog

- [Find more sustainable travel options with new search tools](https://blog.google/products/travel/find-more-sustainable-travel-options-with-new-search-tools/)
- [New ways to browse hotels and save money on flights — plus other tools for summer travel](https://blog.google/products/travel/flight-deals-hotel-browsing-google-search-features/)
- [3 Google Maps updates for trip planning and exploring](https://blog.google/products/maps/google-maps-updates-immersive-view-trip-planning/)